# kendoui grid hierarchical , how do I pass a parent value?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've a KendoUI grid that has inside another grid as childtemplate

in the inner grid I've a Create button and when I save I've to retrieve the value passed from the main grid to the parent...I don't know how to pass it...

Here's my code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<xxx.Lib.Models.Richiesta.Richiesta>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.GUID).Hidden();
    columns.Bound(p => p.UTENTE).Title("Utente").Width(100);
    columns.Bound(p => p.ORA_ESECUZIONE).Title("Ora Esecuzione").ClientTemplate("#= moment(ORA_ESECUZIONE).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss') #");
    columns.Bound(p => p.STATO).Title("Stato");
    columns.Bound(p => p.NOTE).Title("Note");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ID_FREQUENZA).Title("Frequenza").ClientTemplate("#=FREQUENZA#").EditorTemplateName("Frequenza");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ID_TIPO_RICHIESTA).Title("Tipo Richiesta").ClientTemplate("#=TIPO_RICHIESTA#").EditorTemplateName("TipoRichiesta");
    columns.Bound(p => p.SORGENTE).Title("Sorgente");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ORA_INSERIMENTO).Title("Ora Inserimento").ClientTemplate("#= moment(ORA_ESECUZIONE).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss') #");
    columns.Command(command =>
    {
        command.Edit().Text(" ").UpdateText(" ").CancelText(" ");
        // command.Destroy().Text(" ");
    }).Width(172).Title("");
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.GUID);
           }
         )
        .Create(create => create.Action("EditingInlineCreate", "Richieste"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInlineUpdate", "Richieste"))
    // .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("EditingInlineDestroy", "Richieste"))
)
.Pageable(pager => pager.Refresh(true))
.Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
.Editable(edt =>
    edt.ConfirmDelete("Confermare cancellazione?").Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)
)
.AutoBind(false)
.Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(400))
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
.ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Create().Text("Nuova richiesta");
    //toolbar.Template("Da " + Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(x => x.DateFrom).ToHtmlString() +
    //    " a " + Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(x => x.DateTo).ToHtmlString() + Html.Kendo().Button().Content("Ricerca").Name("btn").Events
    //    (events =>
    //    {
    //        events.Click("LoadData");
    //    }).ToHtmlString() +
    //    "<a class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add' href='#' '>Nuova richiesta</a>");

    //
        //).ToHtmlString() +
        //"<a href=\"/Richieste?grid-mode=insert\" class=\"k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add\"><span class=\"k-icon k-add\"></span>Aggiungi nuovo elemento</a>"

}
)

//onlick='customCommand()
)


@helper GridStrumenti()
{
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<xxx.Lib.Models.Richiesta.StrumentoRichiesta>()
                    .Name("grid_instruments_#=GUID#")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(o => o.STRUMENTO).Title("Strumento");
                        columns.Command(commands =>
                            {
                                commands.Edit().Text("").CancelText("").UpdateText("");
                            });
                    })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .PageSize(5)
                        .Read(read => read.Action("LoadInstrumentDetail", "Richieste", new { guid = "#=GUID#" }))
                        .Model(model =>
                        {
                            model.Id(p => p.STRUMENTO);

                        })
                        .Create(create => create.Action("CreateNuovoStrumento", "Richieste"))
                        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInlineUpdate", "Richieste"))
                    )
                    .Pageable()
                    .Sortable()

                    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                        {
                            toolbar.Create().Text("Inserisci nuovo strumento");
                        })
                            .ToClientTemplate()
)
}
```

The action CreateNuovoStrumento should have a Guid that's the one #=GUID# ...how do I pass this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to pass on the parent Grid ID directly to the Child New object, but there is a work around which I have used hope that it can be of some help to you too.

Step 1: Add Edit event to the Child Grid->

```
    .Events(evnt => evnt.Edit("EditNew"))
```

Step 2: Add the Parent ID to the newly created Child Model via **EditNew JS** as below->

```
function EditNew(e) {        
        if (e.model.STRUMENTO == 0) {
             e.model.set("GUID", e.sender._cellId.substring(10,e.sender._cellId.indexOf("_active")));
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if there is any error in above code.

Comment: Hello I've been able using    .Create(create => create.Action("CreateNuovoStrumento", "Richieste", new { myGuid = "#=GUID#" })).... it works!